# Using Helmet for dynamic Meta data in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet, helmet.js

1) If I use Helmet for dynamic meta data in React Js, Do I have still have to include default meta data in the Index.html or I should completely remove the meta fields from there.

2)  if I use data from API to set Meta data using reactJs dynamically how will that work. What is the best way to get this done using React Js with Redux and I am using PHP backend ?

Comment: Helmet doesn't override the description in index.html.

Comment: @Sharan I noticed that. Any idea on how how to get 2) done ?